# Is there an alias for the local machine name in the Windows 7 login screen?

Tags: windows, windows-7, authentication

We have many computers connected to a AD. The computers names is auto generated. When I want to log in using a local account, I have to figure out what the computer's name is, and log in using the following syntax:

```
[COMPUTER_NAME]\local_account
```

Now I'm wondering if there is an alias that I can use instead?

So instead of logging in using `NB-aw35sdds\local_account`, I can use something like `localhost\local_account`.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Yes, I agree: they completely broke the login screen with Windows Vista. Unfortunately, Windows 7 didn't come to the rescue with a "classic logon" option like it did for most things broken in Vista.

As you imagined, though, there is a simple workaround. Instead of typing your computer name, you can use the following alias:

```
.\
```

So, you can simply type the following to log on to the local workstation:

```
.\UserName
```